# Read file one by one from a directory

Tags: php

I am developing an application using php for personal use. What I want to achieve is :

I have a large number of images in a directory. I want to write some description for every image. I have prepared a DB table with 3 columns : id, image_name(unique constraint) and description.
And to make it work, I have developed a webpage, where I would open each image in the browser, write a description about it, save to the database and then open the next image by clicking next and so on.

However, I couldn't figure out how to achieve it. If I do something like :

```
$dir = "/images/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
      echo "filename:" . $file . "<br>";
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

Then I would end up opening n-1 images always , before I reach the nth image.

Comment: do the imagenames have a structure ?   like  1.jpg 2.jpg, .... 500.jpg  ?

Comment: Not sure if i'm understanding the question correctly but I'd use scandir over opendir first, http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php. Then sort that array of files and use the key of that array in the link for the next button.

Answer (score 1):

I would first import the files into the database. Not the actual files , but just a reference to the file in the folder.
(this is not the complete code, but you'll get the point)

```
$files = array_diff( scandir("/path/to/directory"), array(".", "..") ); 
foreach($files as $file) {
    //insert a reference into the database 
    $query = "insert into table_name (image_name) values $file;";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Once they are in place you can easily query them by the Id.

A webpage would look something like this:

```
<?php
$imageId= (int)$_GET['id'];
$row = mysql_fetch_array("select * from table_name where id=$imageId"); 
?>

<html><body>
<a href="?id=<?php echo $imageId + 1; ?>"> Next image </a> 
<img src="<? echo $row['image_name']; ?> ">  
your form here...
```

and go to your page using for example http://127.0.0.1/images/index.php?id=1

Comment: Never put user input directly into your SQL query.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

At a minimum cast it. `$imageId= (int)$_GET['id'];`

Comment: @chris85, it was stated that it is for personal use, not a public website. but sure, it is better to add some security measures.

Comment: Though I am late here to view the answer, but this was exactly I did. I saved all entries first into the DB and then picked one by one from the db. I kept record of the last viewed file into a cookie as suggested by @Andrei

Answer (score 0):

Using browser you cannot do it because between web requests PHP does not keep its state.

What you can do is:

1. Keep the last image number in a cookie - on next request you will read it and skip to the desired number (you still have to skip).
2. Send the whole list of files from PHP to your browser and navigate through it within one page using Javascript and AJAX requests.
3. Keep the list and/or the current number in your database in some temporary table. So each time you send the request to PHP script, it will first check if saved data exists.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to find an image that doesn't exist in the database already and request a description for it, this would make the php to be like:

```
if (!empty($_POST['image'])) {
    // Save the image / description in the db
}
$existing = array(); // Fill this array with the image names that exist in the db.
$dir = "/images/";
// Open a directory, and read its contents
$file = null;
if (is_dir($dir)){
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
            if (!in_array($file, $existing)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
if ($file === null) {
    die('something is wrong, I can not get any files');
}
// set the $file to your view
```

And in the html I would have something like this:

```
<form action="">
    Image: <input name="image" type="text" value="<?php echo $file; ?>"/>
    Description: <input name="description" type="text" value="<?php echo $file; ?>"/>
</form>
```